# PySwip error on launching : cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, python-3.x, prolog, swi-prolog

im having so many troubles setup [pyswip](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip) library and there is not solution inside the repository issues.

I have:

- Python : `3.7.3`
- Swipl: `8.0.3`

Always getting this error message.

```
Please enter you SWI-Prolog version in format "X.Y.Z": 8.0.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/enzoftware/Projects/github-curious/pyswiptest/pyswip_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyswip/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pyswip.prolog import Prolog
  File "/Users/enzoftware/Projects/github-curious/pyswiptest/pyswip_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyswip/prolog.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pyswip.core import *
  File "/Users/enzoftware/Projects/github-curious/pyswiptest/pyswip_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyswip/core.py", line 568, in <module>
    (_path, SWI_HOME_DIR) = _findSwipl()
  File "/Users/enzoftware/Projects/github-curious/pyswiptest/pyswip_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyswip/core.py", line 420, in _findSwipl
    (path, swiHome) = _findSwiplMacOSHome()
  File "/Users/enzoftware/Projects/github-curious/pyswiptest/pyswip_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyswip/core.py", line 342, in _findSwiplMacOSHome
    swi_ver = get_swi_ver()
  File "/Users/enzoftware/Projects/github-curious/pyswiptest/pyswip_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyswip/core.py", line 310, in get_swi_ver
    match = re.search(r'[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]')
TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```